# How to insert multiple rows of data into a table variable if my data is returned from the function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this function.

```
select * from dbo.flsSplitString('1,2,3',',')
```

It returns three rows 1, 2 and 3,
Now I have declared a table variable

```
DECLARE @IDList TABLE
(
    ID varchar(200)
);
```

Now i have to insert the rows returned by the split function to table variable. Function may return as many rows per the requirement. How could i do that?

Comment: normally, combination of `insert into @IDList` and `select * from flsSplitString`. You sure that is what you are asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this

```
Insert Into @IDList (ID)
SELECT [value] -- Use the Column name returned from the SQL Function
FROM dbo.flsSplitString('1,2,3',',')
```

Comment: thanks...what should i do if i have to insert into table just like this with other options just like ....insert into [Product] (Id,Type)values(SELECT [value] 
FROM dbo.flsSplitString('1,2,3',','), @Type)

Comment: @user3624888 Yes you are right. Try  `Insert into [Product] (Id,Type) (SELECT [value] FROM dbo.flsSplitString('1,2,3',','), @Type)`